# Drop down side menu single column like google maps app any suggestions of examples?

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anyone know the code for this 1 colum dropdown menu? I know its basic I just don’t know it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406719/does-anyone-know-the-code-for-this-1-colum-dropdown-menu-i-know-its-basic-i-jus)

Basically i'm looking for this drop down menu. With opacity. Pinned to the top like google maps app does. I'm trying to copy the andoid google maps opacity header and drop down menu app...

Here it is

http://www.siliconrepublic.com/new-media/item/30071-google-maps-for-ios-6-expec

I got this from motools but it's not what google app looks like

http://gofi.netai.net/

Answer (score 0):

```
menu {
opacity:0.1;
filter:alpha(opacity=10); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Replacing the values for each accordingly. You can make any HTML tag opaque using this CSS. Even existing menus from motools.